# How to properly redirect (while setting a cookie) in MVC3/Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

First off, I get the feeling that Response.Redirect is just a leftover from classic ASP, and I should be using something else in the MVC paradigm.

And second, while my current implementation of Response.Redirect IS working, it doesn't set the cookie I want it to.  I'm assuming this is because the header gets wiped out instead of sent to the client on redirect.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form)
    {
        User user;
        string sessionKey;

        if (UserManager.Login(form["Email"], form["Password"]))
        {
            // Login stuff here

            // Remember user's email
            Response.Cookies["Email"].Value = form["Email"];
            Response.Cookies["Email"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(31);

            // Redirect to homepage
            Response.Redirect("~/");
        }
     }
```

Comment: @Slaks, it only stores the email in a cookie, it does not use it.  You still need my password.

Comment: Huh? How do you check whether a user is logged in?

Comment: UserManager.Login returns a bool, and also handles encryption, etc.

Comment: Theres also other proprietary code where it says "Login Stuff Here" that was not relevant to this question.

Comment: I see.  I thought you were relying on that cookie.  Sorry.

Comment: Na, all it's used for is when the user is NOT logged in the next time, if they checked the "Remember my Email" checkbox, it will put it in the form for them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper way to redirect in MVC is `return RedirectToAction("Home", "Index")`.

The cookies should work.

Comment: Does it actually change the url in the browser as well?  Or will the user still see Home/Login ?

Comment: It's a real redirect.  It calls `Response.Redirect` under the covers after resolving the URL.