# Cookie not getting created when redirecting?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have the following in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Login(string email, string password)
    {
        /* 
           some stuff 
           ...
        */
        HttpCookie CustomerCookie = new HttpCookie("Customer");
        CustomerCookie.Values.Add("FirstName", Customer.FirstName);
        CustomerCookie.Values.Add("LastName", Customer.LastName);
        CustomerCookie.Values.Add("Email", email);
        CustomerCookie.Secure = true;
        Response.Cookies.Add(CustomerCookie);
        return RedirectToAction("OrderType", "Order");
    }
```

But for some reason when I look for the cookie it is nowhere to be found after the redirect.  Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372987/how-to-properly-redirect-while-setting-a-cookie-in-mvc3-razor) I was assuming that the method above would work.

Can anyone see why my cookie is not being created here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some troubleshooting steps I would take:

- Remove the redirect and just return an empty view and see if the cookie is there
- Do not set Secure to true and see if that's the issue
- Force a response flush to see if there's an action filter or something post action execution that's preventing the cookie from being returned in the response
- Use fiddler to look at the actual http response for the cookie in case your browser is preventing cookies

Comment: Gah - it was totally the secure flag!  I forgot that I'm not using a secure connection when I run locally.  Thanks!